# appendChild is not a function using $.confirm()

Tags: javascript, jquery-confirm

good day, I'm struggling to solve this problem. I spent 1 day to try to solve this problem but no luck for me.

I am trying to append a child inside onContentReady function on $.confirm() but seems doesn't work for me. here is the code

**html**

```
<button onclick="btnclick()">click</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function btnclick() {
    // body...
    $.confirm({
    title:'test',
    content: '<div class=".confirm_body"> </div>',
    onContentReady:function() {

        var body = this.$content.find('.confirm_body');

        var h3 = document.createElement('h3');
        h3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("child"));
        body.appendChild(h3);
    }
   });
  }
```

**exception**

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: body.appendChild is not a function TypeError: body.appendChild is not a function
    at Jconfirm.onContentReady (http://localhost/NMSCST_CLINIC_INFORMATION_SYSTEM/:154:8)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost/NMSCST_CLINIC_INFORMATION_SYSTEM/assets/jquery-confirm-v3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js:10:6129)
    at j (http://localhost/NMSCST_CLINIC_INFORMATION_SYSTEM/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:29568)
    at k (http://localhost/NMSCST_CLINIC_INFORMATION_SYSTEM/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:29882) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
```

my code doesn't display the child.

What should I do? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess your selector is not correct in `this.$content.find('confirm_body')`, if `confirm_body` is `id` of element then use `#`, like,

```
...
onContentReady:function() {

    var body = this.$content.find('.confirm_body');

    var h3 = document.createElement('h3');
    h3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("child"));
    body.append($(h3)); //make jQuery object for h3 element node & use append
}
...
```

Comment: @basaya you need to use .append() instead of appendChild as in my answer above, as body is jQuery object in your case

Comment: thank you, appendChild doesn't work.. appreciate your correct answer sir

Answer (score 1):

`body` is a jQuery object, not a DOM object, so you should use

```
body.append($(h3));
```

It would be a good idea to be more consistent as well, to stick to using all jQuery methods, rather than mixing up native DOM elements and jQuery objects.